# table legend - wrong reference

Tags: tables, legend

I'm using these commands to create a table with a legend, but the problem is that when I make a reference to it, it appears as "Table IIIB" instead of "Table III".

Can you help me please ?

```
\begingroup
\squeezetable
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{ruledtabular}
%\centering
\caption{Difference between the potential energy of different types of atoms and the average potential energy of the system : $\Delta$E = E - E\textsubscript{ave} (E\textsubscript{ave} = -3.016 eV/at.)}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
Type of atom & $\Delta$E (eV/at.) & 1\textsuperscript{st} neighbors' $\Delta$E (eV/at.) \\
\hline
a & -0.01863  & - \\
%\hline
b & 0.7002  & -0.03113* \\
%\hline
c & -0.06651  & 0.1377* \\
%\hline
d & 0.1609  & 0.02185*\\
%\hline
e & -0.1137   & 0.1440*  \\
%\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\label{Epot}
\\
\begin{flushleft}
a : tetracoordinated atom with no defective neighbors\\
b : tricoordinated atom\\
c : five-coordinated atom\\
d : five-coordinated atom belonging to a triangular geometry**\\
e : five-coordinated atom not belonging to a triangular geometry**\\
* Only tetracoordinated atoms\\
** Triangular geometry refers to a three-membered ring formed of 5-coordinated atoms only
\end{flushleft}
\end{table}
\endgroup
```

Comment: your example is incomplete so I can't test but I would guess you need `\label` inside the `ruledtabular` preferably immediately after `\caption{..}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the label inside the `ruledtablular` environment; otherwise, incurs error reference. Since the complete code was not given, this solution managed to find needed packages to make a run.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subscript}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\squeezetable
\begin{table}[!hbt]
\begin{ruledtabular}
%\centering
\caption{Difference between the potential energy of different types of atoms and the average potential energy of the system : $\Delta$E = E - E\textsubscript{ave} (E\textsubscript{ave} = -3.016 eV/at.)}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
Type of atom & $\Delta$E (eV/at.) & 1\textsuperscript{st} neighbors' $\Delta$E (eV/at.) \\
\hline
a & -0.01863  & - \\
%\hline
b & 0.7002  & -0.03113* \\
%\hline
c & -0.06651  & 0.1377* \\
%\hline
d & 0.1609  & 0.02185*\\
%\hline
e & -0.1137   & 0.1440*  \\
%\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{Epot}
\end{ruledtabular}

\begin{flushleft}
a : tetracoordinated atom with no defective neighbors\\
b : tricoordinated atom\\
c : five-coordinated atom\\
d : five-coordinated atom belonging to a triangular geometry**\\
e : five-coordinated atom not belonging to a triangular geometry**\\
* Only tetracoordinated atoms\\
** Triangular geometry refers to a three-membered ring formed of 5-coordinated atoms only
\end{flushleft}
\end{table}
\endgroup

Table \ref{Epot} shows the first table.

\section{Test}
\begingroup
\squeezetable
\begin{table}[!hbt]
\begin{ruledtabular}
%\centering
\caption{Difference between the potential energy of different types of atoms and the average potential energy of the system : $\Delta$E = E - E\textsubscript{ave} (E\textsubscript{ave} = -3.016 eV/at.)}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
Type of atom & $\Delta$E (eV/at.) & 1\textsuperscript{st} neighbors' $\Delta$E (eV/at.) \\
\hline
a & -0.01863  & - \\
%\hline
b & 0.7002  & -0.03113* \\
%\hline
c & -0.06651  & 0.1377* \\
%\hline
d & 0.1609  & 0.02185*\\
%\hline
e & -0.1137   & 0.1440*  \\
%\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{EpotA}
\end{ruledtabular}
\begin{flushleft}
a : tetracoordinated atom with no defective neighbors\\
b : tricoordinated atom\\
c : five-coordinated atom\\
d : five-coordinated atom belonging to a triangular geometry**\\
e : five-coordinated atom not belonging to a triangular geometry**\\
* Only tetracoordinated atoms\\
** Triangular geometry refers to a three-membered ring formed of 5-coordinated atoms only
\end{flushleft}
\end{table}
\endgroup

Table \ref{EpotA} shows the second table, demonstrating the correct reference when label is put inside the ruledtabular environment.

\subsection{A subsection}
\begingroup
\squeezetable
\begin{table}[!hbt]
\begin{ruledtabular}
%\centering
\caption{Difference between the potential energy of different types of atoms and the average potential energy of the system : $\Delta$E = E - E\textsubscript{ave} (E\textsubscript{ave} = -3.016 eV/at.)}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
Type of atom & $\Delta$E (eV/at.) & 1\textsuperscript{st} neighbors' $\Delta$E (eV/at.) \\
\hline
a & -0.01863  & - \\
%\hline
b & 0.7002  & -0.03113* \\
%\hline
c & -0.06651  & 0.1377* \\
%\hline
d & 0.1609  & 0.02185*\\
%\hline
e & -0.1137   & 0.1440*  \\
%\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\label{EpotB}
\begin{flushleft}
a : tetracoordinated atom with no defective neighbors\\
b : tricoordinated atom\\
c : five-coordinated atom\\
d : five-coordinated atom belonging to a triangular geometry**\\
e : five-coordinated atom not belonging to a triangular geometry**\\
* Only tetracoordinated atoms\\
** Triangular geometry refers to a three-membered ring formed of 5-coordinated atoms only
\end{flushleft}
\end{table}
\endgroup

Table \ref{EpotB} shows the third table, depicting the incorrect reference because the label was NOT inside the ruledtabular environment.


\end{document}
```